# when creating custom color, I get "syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens"

Tags: java, syntax, colors, token

This is all I'm trying to do in my program so far:

```
import java.awt.Color;
Color myBrown = new Color(160,96,0);
```

It gives me an error: `syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens`

Any idea what could be the cause?

Comment: Place your code in a class.

Comment: ooooooh, duh.  ok thank you

Comment: `java.awt.Color`'s constructor does take 3 `int`s. Of course, if your `import` statement precedes the variable declaration directly (with no `class` declaration), your code won't compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So rgettman had the right answer - I was trying to do it outside of the class under my include statements rather than in the class.